# Sizing parentheses around tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, parentheses

I'd like to put parentheses around a picture I'm drawing with `tikz`. I tried using `\left(` and `\right` but this gives me parentheses twice the height of the picture, with the picture only occupying the top half of space within the parentheses. How can I get parentheses the same size as the picture?

So far I have:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[ \left( \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2] \draw [magenta, line width =1mm] (0,-1) rectangle (4,3); \draw [magenta, line width=1mm] (4,-1) rectangle (6,-3); \end{tikzpicture} \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `baseline` key

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[ \left( \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,baseline=-1mm] 
\draw [magenta, line width=1mm] (0,-1) rectangle (4,3); 
\draw [magenta, line width=1mm] (4,-1) rectangle (6,-3); 
\end{tikzpicture} \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better yet, `baseline=-\the\fontdimen22\textfont2`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment

Comment: This solution did not work for me.  It seems it depends on which range of coordinates are used by the tikzpicture itself.  @Rmano's answer worked better.

Answer (score 2):

Using the comment by @greg and the answers of [Align an equation and a tikz picture with anchor and baseline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75194/align-an-equation-and-a-tikz-picture-with-anchor-and-baseline), I would in this case use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[ A = \left(\,
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2, 
                baseline={([yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
                    current bounding box.center)},
        ] 
            \draw [magenta, line width =1mm] (0,-1) rectangle (4,3); 
            \draw [magenta, line width=1mm] (4,-1) rectangle (6,-3); 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \,\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

...to center the center of the figure with the `=` sign, and I would add a bit of space `\,` around the figure.

[image: Result]