# Parentheses around tikzpicture add blank space

Tags: tikz-pgf, parentheses

I want to add parentheses around a tikzpicture. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302449/sizing-parentheses-around-tikzpicture) give a simple solution.

However, in my case it doesn't work well. As shown by the following MWE, parentheses add a blank space at the top of the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \frametitle{test}
\[ \left( \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\fontdimen22\textfont2,
    declare function={
      excitation(\t,\w) = sin(\t*\w);
      noise = rnd - 0.5;
      source(\t) = excitation(\t,20) + noise;
      filter(\t) = 1 - abs(sin(mod(\t, 50)));
      speech(\t) = 1 + source(\t)*filter(\t);
    }
  ]
    \draw[orange, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=-.5cm] (0,1) -- plot [domain=0:360, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{speech(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture} \right)
\]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I proceed to make parentheses fit around the tikz waveform, **without the additional blank space**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`baseline=(current bounding box.center)` works better.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\[ \left( \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    declare function={
      excitation(\t,\w) = sin(\t*\w);
      noise = rnd - 0.5;
      source(\t) = excitation(\t,20) + noise;
      filter(\t) = 1 - abs(sin(mod(\t, 50)));
      speech(\t) = 1 + source(\t)*filter(\t);
    }
  ]
    \draw[orange, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=-.5cm] (0,1) -- plot [domain=0:360, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{speech(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture} \right)
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```