# Equations using Tree Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, trees

I would like to write an equation over binary trees. Here is the code I have so far:
`

```
\[
\begin{array}{lcr}
\sum(-1)^{p+qr} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
        \node[circle] at (1,-1) {$\gamma_q$};
        \node[circle] at (1,-2.5) {$f_k$};
        \draw[thick] (0.5,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (0.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (2,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-2.75) -- (1,-3.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    -\sum(-1)^{\varepsilon}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
        \node[circle] at (0,-1) {$f_{j_1}$};
        \node[circle] at (1.35,-1) {$f_{j_i}$};
        \node[circle] at (2.55,-1) {$f_{j_k}$};
        \node[circle] at (1,-2.5) {$\rho_k$};
        \node[circle] at (0.6,-1) {$\ldots$};
        \node[circle] at (2.0,-1) {$\dots$};
        \draw[thick] (-0.6,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (-0.2,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0.25,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.0,0) -- (1.35,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.4,0) -- (1.35,-0.7); 
        \draw[thick] (2.9,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.8,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (3.1,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (0.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (2.2,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-2.75) -- (1,-3.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{array}
\]
```

`
While the trees in the diagram are correct (although probably poor from a coding point of view), the positioning of the summation signs is problematic: I would like them to appear at about the midpoint of each tree.

Is there a way to write equations in TikZ, or is there some other way to improve the placement of the summation symbols?

Comment: Off-topic: If you highlight your code and press the button with {} the code will be placed in it's environment without need of spaces before every line. (Welcome!)

Comment: You could put the two tikzpicture environments into `\raisebox`es.

Comment: I'd use `forest`, but that's just the trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of several possibilities is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{lcr}
\sum(-1)^{p+qr} \vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
        \node[circle] at (1,-1) {$\gamma_q$};
        \node[circle] at (1,-2.5) {$f_k$};
        \draw[thick] (0.5,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (0.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (2,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-2.75) -- (1,-3.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
    &
    -\sum(-1)^{\varepsilon}
    &
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
        \node[circle] at (0,-1) {$f_{j_1}$};
        \node[circle] at (1.35,-1) {$f_{j_i}$};
        \node[circle] at (2.55,-1) {$f_{j_k}$};
        \node[circle] at (1,-2.5) {$\rho_k$};
        \node[circle] at (0.6,-1) {$\ldots$};
        \node[circle] at (2.0,-1) {$\dots$};
        \draw[thick] (-0.6,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (-0.2,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0.25,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.0,0) -- (1.35,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.4,0) -- (1.35,-0.7); 
        \draw[thick] (2.9,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.8,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (3.1,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (0.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (2.2,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-2.75) -- (1,-3.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer! I also tried the raisebox solution proposed by Jasper Habicht, and both did the trick, but this way is slightly nicer looking. Thanks for your help. For some reason, I'm not allowed to accept your answer just yet, but I will attend to that shortly.

Comment: @AnCoileanach Note that you don't really need the `array` at all here, you are after all just writing a few things after one another on the same line.

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
```

with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
```

**addedndum:**
off-topic: trees drawn as tree. also is corrected `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\sum(-1)^{p+qr}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                    grow'=up, anchor=south, scale=0.5,
                    sibling distance=5mm]
\draw (0,0) -- + (0,1) node {$f_k$}
    child
    child
    child { node{$\gamma_q$}
        child
        child
        child
          }
    child
    child
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
    -\sum(-1)^{\varepsilon}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                    grow'=up, anchor=south, scale=0.5,
                    sibling distance=7mm]
\draw (0,0) -- + (0,1) node {$\rho_k$}
    child { node (a) {$f_{j1}$}
        child
        child
        child
          }
    child {node {}}
    child
    child {  node (b) {$f_{j1}$}
        child
        child
        child
          }
    child
    child {node {}}
   child {  node (c) {$f_{jk}$}
        child
        child
        child
          }
    ;
   \draw[dotted, very thick] (a) -- (b)  (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @An Coileanach, i add code for drawing trees. see, if it is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for this - I will definitely use this approach for drawing trees in future.

Comment: @AnCoileanach, complete solution is useful and very consistent :-)

Comment: @Zarko Very nice solution! (+1) What would be the magic line to make the picture vertically centered at the center of the equation (rather than the baseline)?

Comment: `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` :-). this set baseline of picture to it center.

Comment: @marmot A bit of `yshift` would do, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75199/

Answer (score 1):

A tabular solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{m{1.6cm} m{2cm} m{1.2cm} m{2.5cm}}
$\sum(-1)^{p+qr}$ &
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
        \node[circle] at (1,-1) {$\gamma_q$};
        \node[circle] at (1,-2.5) {$f_k$};
        \draw[thick] (0.5,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,0) -- (1,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (0.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (2,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-2.75) -- (1,-3.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &$
    -\sum(-1)^{\varepsilon}
    $&
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
        \node[circle] at (0,-1) {$f_{j_1}$};
        \node[circle] at (1.35,-1) {$f_{j_i}$};
        \node[circle] at (2.55,-1) {$f_{j_k}$};
        \node[circle] at (1,-2.5) {$\rho_k$};
        \node[circle] at (0.6,-1) {$\ldots$};
        \node[circle] at (2.0,-1) {$\dots$};
        \draw[thick] (-0.6,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (-0.2,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0.25,0) -- (0,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.0,0) -- (1.35,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.4,0) -- (1.35,-0.7); 
        \draw[thick] (2.9,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (1.8,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (3.1,0) -- (2.4,-0.7);
        \draw[thick] (0,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (0.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1.5,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (2.2,-1.3) -- (1,-2.2);
        \draw[thick] (1,-2.75) -- (1,-3.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also a nice approach! Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Welcome (since you already tried to accept -no matter which answer- and could not, I gave you some points to have this advantage... :P). Welcome and happy TeXing.

Comment: @koleygr Questioners can always accept answers. Upvoting is restricted, though, so people need some points to reward multiple answers to the same question or answers to other people's questions.

Comment: @cfr thanks for the info... I thought that he needed at least 10 points... Could not imagine something else... Good to know because it would be really bad idea not to be like this...