# Vertically centering symbols and graphics inside math formulas

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, fontspec, unicode-math

I want to use some symbols from dingbat font [Dingosaurs](https://www.dafont.com/ding-o-saurs.font) and graphics inside math formulas. However, they are aligned to the bottom, while I want them to be vertically centered.

[image]

How can I do it inside both inline and centered equations?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Dingosaurs.ttf}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

    $1+\text{A}=2$

    $\displaystyle1+\text{A}=2$

    \[
        1+\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{a.png}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The adjustbox package has an export feature that adds its features to `\includegraphics ` directly, perhaps the the `valign=c`  option is all that is needed. (the option might be named differently, did not check)

Comment: @daleif I need the fonts more, than the image, so this is not the solution, unfortunately

Comment: Ahh sorry, my bad did not notice that font, but the standalone `\adjustbox` macro still do what you want, and more.

Comment: I don't think this is a fontspec or unicode-math question, really.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In math-mode, you can easily vertically center a picture using `\vcenter{\hbox{..}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Dingosaurs.ttf}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

    $1+\text{A}=2$

    $\displaystyle1+\text{A}=2$
    \[
        1+\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{a.png}}} + 1+\text{A}=2
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Maybe create a macro called, say, `\cbox`, as `\newcommand\cbox[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}` in the preamble, and then write `1+\cbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{a}}` in the body of the document? (The `.png` extension isn't strictly necessary.)

Answer (score 7):

The following macro `\TextVCenter` centers text vertically around the math axis. It respects the different math styles and also works in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\dingo{Dingosaurs.ttf}

\newcommand*{\TextVCenter}[1]{%
  \text{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}%
}

\begin{document}

  1 + \TextVCenter{\dingo A} = 2

  $\displaystyle 1 + \TextVCenter{\dingo A} = 2$

  $\scriptstyle 1 + \TextVCenter{\dingo A} = 2$

  $\scriptscriptstyle 1 + \TextVCenter{\dingo A} = 2$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\text` from package `amstext` (or loaded by `amsmath` or `mathtools`) adapts the text sizes to the math style.
- `\vcenter` is a math command for centering vertical box material vertically around the math axis.
- `\hbox` in opposite to `\mbox` avoids that a new paragraph with width `\hsize` starts in the vertical box of `\vcenter`.

And with the tail sticking to the left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\dingo{Dingosaurs.ttf}

\newcommand*{\TextVCenter}[1]{%
  \text{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}%
}

\newcommand*{\DingoA}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mkern-9mu\relax
    \TextVCenter{\dingo A}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

  1 + \DingoA = 2

  $\displaystyle 1 + \DingoA = 2$

  $\scriptstyle 1 + \DingoA = 2$

  $\scriptscriptstyle 1 + \DingoA = 2$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use (or abuse, perhaps) `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
1+\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}\end{tabular}=2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Original and very beautiful you code +1.

Comment: The faint horizontal line through `example-image-a` indicates that the object isn't centered on the math axis. Is there a way to adjust the (vertical) centering?

Comment: Perhaps easier with adjustbox

Comment: Btw wouldn't the plain matrix env do the same as this tabular?

Comment: @daleif Yes, but this exits from math mode.

Comment: Which is relevant why?

Comment: @daleif For the dinosaurs?

Comment: Right, it's a text font

Answer (score 3):

A simple `\raisebox` can also do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

     \[
        1+\raisebox{-0.45\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{Pointe_du_jour}}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `-0.45\totalheight`, not `.5`, is it a manual tweak?

Comment: Yes, it is, to centre the image w.r.t.  the math axis, not the baseline. Rigourously done, I should have written `\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\totalheight+\fontdimen22\textfont2}`, but I thought that for casual use, an approximation was enough.

Answer (score 1):

Edit after @barbara's comment (with a complicated equation to make visible the defference):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\newsavebox{\helpbox}
\newlength{\myshift}
\newcommand\addpic[2][]{\savebox{\helpbox}{\vbox{$.\cdot$}}\setlength\myshift{0.5\ht\helpbox}\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, outer sep=0,inner sep=0,yshift=\myshift]\node[outer sep=0,inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}


    \[
    \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3}}^{\displaystyle\int_{N=\dfrac{1}{3}}^{9^5}f(x)+4 dx}+\addpic[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}=1
    \]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Old answer:**
A tikz solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}


    \[
    \tikz[anchor=center, baseline] \node {$\frac{1}{\frac{2}{3}}-$};\tikz[anchor=center,baseline] \node {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}};\tikz[anchor=center,baseline]\node{$=1$};
    \]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

And if we add `inner sep=0` in tikz options:

[image]

Comment: the minus sign on the left doesn't seem to be aligned exactly with the equals sign on the right, judging from the centerline on the graphic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks... You are right... If you change with `\dfrac` you will find out it isn't aligned at all.

Comment: @barbarabeeton... Think that fixed the prioblem! Thanks...