# How to make an equation of Venn Diagrams with the symbols aligned properly?

Tags: venn-diagrams

Essentially what the question says.

My code right now is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}
-
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillACapB
\end{venndiagram2sets}
=
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillOnlyA
\end{venndiagram2sets}
$

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Equation of Venn Diagrams]

Of course, I'd like to have the minus and equal sign vertically centered. Is this possible?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417830/ also works here (with three separate `\raisebox` commands for the Venn diagrams).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

$
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}}}
-
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillACapB
\end{venndiagram2sets}}}
=
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillOnlyA
\end{venndiagram2sets}}}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another way to do it from something I had done previously.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

$
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}}
-
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillACapB
\end{venndiagram2sets}}
=
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\begin{venndiagram2sets}[showframe = false] 
\fillOnlyA
\end{venndiagram2sets}}
$

\end{document}
```