# Middle line height point with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do a command in LaTeX named `\facil` where:

1. I read the counter `ejercicio`, I add 1 to it and I display it with sans-serif font, and then write down a dot. I've previously created it in the preamble, and the code I've done:

   ```
   {%
   \sffamily\arabic{ejercicio}%
   \addtocounter{ejercicio}{1}.%
   }%
   ```
2. Then write a space with "\ " (without quotes) and draw a blue circle (or point) where is exactly in the middle of the line, with color `blue!25!black` and `minimum size=1ex`. That's what I don't know how to do it, I've tried with `baseline` option but I haven't done anything right.
3. Write a large space "\;" (the text "Representa en forma..." is not part of the command).

An image of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: So `\facil` should do 1. 2. and 3.?

Comment: Yes, `\facil` should be "1. * ", I mean, the counter followed by a dot, the middle circle and the thick space.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{ejercicio}
\newcommand\facil{%
  \stepcounter{ejercicio}{\sffamily\theejercicio.}~\textcolor{blue!25!black}{$\bullet$}~}

\begin{document}

\facil Representa en forma de intervalo...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\raisebox` and/or `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package you can change the attributes for the `\bullet`; for example:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{ejercicio}
\newcommand\facil{%
  \stepcounter{ejercicio}{\sffamily\theejercicio.}~\textcolor{blue!25!black}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\bullet$}}~}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228), I am guessing the problem with what you were attempting was to apply `baseline` to the `\draw`, or `\node`. It needs to be applied to the `\tikz`.  Here is what I think you were doing incorrectly (shown in red) and a way to fix it:

[image]

### References:

- [How to align a series of TikZ pictures at the baseline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58281/how-to-align-a-series-of-tikz-pictures-at-the-baseline)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{ejercicio}

\newcommand{\Oldfacil}{%
    \addtocounter{ejercicio}{1}%
    \sffamily\arabic{ejercicio}.~%
    \tikz \draw [fill=red, yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) circle (2pt);~%
}%

\newcommand{\facil}{%
    \addtocounter{ejercicio}{1}%
    \sffamily\arabic{ejercicio}.~%
    \tikz[baseline] \draw [fill=blue!25!black, yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) circle (2pt);~%
}%
\begin{document}
\Oldfacil Baseline applied to \verb|\draw|

\facil Baseline applied to \verb|\tikz|
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it also a good solution. I can ask you from my ignorance why are you using `.75 ex`, and not other distance?

Comment: I adjusted that value so that it looked right, and used the `ex` units so that it will adjust if the font size is changed.