# TikZ node in normal text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes, baseline

I would like to place a TikZ node inside normal text to get the fancy boxes. But the box is on the same baseline. I would like to get the text on the baseline. What can I do?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Not all characters are at the same baseline \tikz{\node [rounded corners,draw] {X};}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that you can format code blocks by preceding each line by 4 white spaces, or by selecting the block and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: have you seen [How to align a series of TikZ pictures at the baseline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58281)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to use the key `baseline` with a named node to tell TikZ where is the baseline

The anchor of the baseline for a node is named `base`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Not all characters are at the same baseline \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{\node [rounded corners,draw] (n) {X};}
\end{document}
```