# Cross out words with overlapping to nearby words

Tags: tcolorbox, draw

I have figured out how to add a cross over words with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Of course, presenting this solution would be cheating. And, no, it won't work in all cases, due to strict limitations on the pairs 
\tcbox[tcbox raise base,
breakable,nobeforeafter, enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=0, sharp corners, parbox=false, boxrule=0pt, top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, frame hidden, parbox=false, 
  finish={\draw[thick,red] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);\draw[thick,red] (frame.south east)--(frame.north west);}]{
  accepted
  }
  by \textbackslash{}line. Your professor surely knows that TeX doesn't draw oblique lines. With the standard package pict2e it's easier and it will work in any case.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I cross out word accept. However, I want the cross to stretch out a bit, say 1cm, see my illustration.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Off topic: use `\verb|\line|` instead of `\textbackslash{}line`; use `\TeX{}` instead of `TeX` and use `\verb|pict2e|` instead  of `pict2e`.

Comment: @JouleV thanks, but just copied random text on texoverflow for illustration purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `shorten` your lines.

[image: shortened]

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tikzset{crossout/.style={thick,red,shorten >=-.5cm,shorten <=-.5cm}}

\begin{document}

Of course, presenting this solution would be cheating. And, no, it won't work in all cases, due to strict limitations on the pairs 
\tcbox[tcbox raise base,
breakable,nobeforeafter, enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=0, sharp corners, parbox=false, boxrule=0pt, top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, frame hidden, parbox=false, 
  finish={\draw[crossout] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);\draw[crossout] (frame.south east)--(frame.north west);}]{
  accepted
  }
  by \textbackslash{}line. Your professor surely knows that TeX doesn't draw oblique lines. With the standard package pict2e it's easier and it will work in any case.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Can you add a bit explanation? I'm new to this package, I didn't find explanation of `\tikzset` in the package documentation. Can you explain that? Also what is `/.`?

Comment: @Gqqnbig Which documentation are you reading? `\tikzset` is defined in the `tikz` package which you are using for the overlays (`finish` in this case). And a negative shorten just extends one end of the line.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative TikZ solution (less elegant than TeXnician's one).

With `overlay` you can write over something without occupy space.

I've used `shift` to enlarge the lines (you can use `shorten` also here, but I haven't used it because TeXnician already did it, hence I would like to show an alternative).

To align TikZ nodes to normal text, see here: [TikZ node in normal text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98937/tikz-node-in-normal-text).

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mycrossed}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture, baseline=(A.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt](A){#1};
        }%
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{
        \draw[red, very thick] ([shift={(-.5,.2)}]A.north west) -- ([shift={(.5,-.2)}]A.south east);
        \draw[red, very thick] ([shift={(-.5,-.2)}]A.south west) -- ([shift={(.5,.2)}]A.north east);
        }%
    }
\begin{document}

Of course, presenting this solution would be cheating. And, no, it won't work in all cases, due to strict limitations on the pairs 
\mycrossed{accepted}
  by \textbackslash{}line. Your professor surely knows that TeX doesn't draw oblique lines. With the standard package pict2e it's easier and it will work in any case.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In May 2019 ([pgf version 3.1.3](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.3)) tikz already has the cross out shape in its `shapes.misc` library.

The following code and figure is taken from Section 71.8 of the manual.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\node [cross out,draw=red] at (1.5,1) {cross out};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]