# How do I put \begin{align} in tcbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to cross out sentences and equations. I used the solution given in [Cross out words with overlapping to nearby words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478554/cross-out-words-with-overlapping-to-nearby-words)

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tikzset{crossout/.style={thick,red,shorten >=-.5cm,shorten <=-.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\tcbox[tcbox raise base,
breakable,nobeforeafter, enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=0, sharp corners, parbox=false, boxrule=0pt, top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, frame hidden, parbox=false, 
  finish={\draw[crossout] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);\draw[crossout] (frame.south east)--(frame.north west);}]{

  Therefore we have

  \begin{align*}
(t=1, m=[0], s=(2,2)) \otimes (t=1, m=[0], s=(4,4)) &= (1, [0,2], (4,4)) \\
(t=3, m=[0], s=(4,4)) \otimes (t=3, m=[0], s=(5,5)) &= (3, [0,4], (5,5)) \\
\end{align*}

}

\end{document}
```

But it throws exception:

```
Missing \endgroup inserted.

<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.18 }

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

 name.tex, line 18
Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 
                }
l.18 }

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

 name.tex, line 18
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{align*}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 }

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using `tcolorbox`?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tikzset{crossout/.style={thick,red,shorten >=-.5cm,shorten <=-.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  nobeforeafter,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  opacityback=0,
  sharp corners,
  parbox=false,
  boxrule=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  finish={
    \draw[crossout] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);
    \draw[crossout] (frame.south east)--(frame.north west);
  }
]
Therefore we have
\begin{align*}
(t=1, m=[0], s=(2,2)) \otimes (t=1, m=[0], s=(4,4)) &= (1, [0,2], (4,4)) \\
(t=3, m=[0], s=(4,4)) \otimes (t=3, m=[0], s=(5,5)) &= (3, [0,4], (5,5))
\end{align*}
Be careful not to do this.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy to put align into boxes (you essentially have to use a minipage), so `tcolorbox` has a key for the AMS environments. In your case, one can use `ams align* lower`. Of course, one needs to remove the separator with `lower separated=false`. I also switched to `\begin{tcolorbox}...\end{tcolorbox}` instead of `\tcbox{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tikzset{crossout/.style={thick,red,shorten >=-.5cm,shorten <=-.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tcbox raise base,
breakable,ams align* lower,lower separated=false,
nobeforeafter, enhanced jigsaw, opacityback=0, sharp corners, 
parbox=false,
boxrule=0pt, top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt, boxsep=0pt, frame hidden,
  finish={\draw[crossout] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);
  \draw[crossout] (frame.south east)--(frame.north west);}]
  Therefore we have
\tcblower
(t=1, m=[0], s=(2,2)) \otimes (t=1, m=[0], s=(4,4)) &= (1, [0,2], (4,4)) \\
(t=3, m=[0], s=(4,4)) \otimes (t=3, m=[0], s=(5,5)) &= (3, [0,4], (5,5)) \\
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I put text after the equations?

Comment: @Gqqnbig I do not think that this is possible out of the box. You could use e.g. `aligned` instead of `align`.

Comment: @Gqqnbig However, if you only want to cross out some text with some `align` environment, this can be achieved much easier, you do not need `tcolorbox` for that. You can also just use a `minipage` but will of course lose `breakable` then.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining what you want with `pstricks` is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psDefBoxNodes{E}{\centering%
$ \begin{aligned}
 (t=1, m=[0], s=(2,2)) \otimes (t=1, m=[0], s=(4,4)) &= (1, [0,2], (4,4)) \\
(t=3, m=[0], s=(4,4)) \otimes (t=3, m=[0], s=(5,5)) &= (3, [0,4], (5,5))
\end{aligned} $%
}%
\psset{linecolor=red, nodesep=1.5em}
\ncline{E:tl}{E:br}
\ncline{E:bl}{E:tr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem regarding `tcolorbox`, does it? Crossing out some stuff can be achieve in multiple ways without forcing the OP to compile with `-shell-escape` or `xelatex`.

Comment: It doesn't indeed, and I didn't claim so. I just wanted to show the *result * could be obtained with a short code.

Comment: The OP has a `breakable` in their box, and some text above the equation. Does your short code also allow one to have the thing break over two or more pages?

Comment: If it is put inside the \tcolorbox, I guess so, provided the crossed out equation is not broken, of course (not tested).

Comment: The OP crosses out the whole box, not just the equation.

Comment: That was not obvious to me from the code. If the box is not broken, it can be put in a minipage and it will still work.

Comment: As I said, there are many simple(r) options to cross out some part of the text, an equation and so on, this site is full of this. I hope the OP does not only want this because IMHO this is an interesting question how one may combine all the nice features `tcolorbox` offers with `align`, say.